# Java - Trying to set background image to my GUI Interface

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;                    
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;     
import java.io.IOException;  
                //////////////////////////////////
                //   3nriched Games Presents:   //
                //      MIPS The Mouse!!        //
                //////////////////////////////////           


public class mipsMouseGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
   {

    private static String ThePDub = ("mouse"); //the password
    JPasswordField pass;
    JPanel panel;
    JButton btnEnter;
    JLabel lblpdub;

        public mipsMouseGUI()
        {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try { //attempts to read picture from the folder
            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/mousepics/mousepic.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {  //catches exceptions
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setIconImage(image);  //sets icon picture



            setTitle("Mips The Mouse Login");

            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            panel = new JPanel(); //creates a panel
            ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("/mousepics/backgroundspacepic.jpeg").getImage());

            pass = new JPasswordField(5);  //sets password length to 5          


            pass.setEchoChar('@');   //hide characters as @ symbol
            pass.addActionListener(this);    //adds action listener


            add(panel);  //adds panel to frame
            btnEnter = new JButton("Enter"); //creates a button     
            btnEnter.addActionListener(this);// Register the action listener.

            lblpdub = new JLabel("       Your Password: "); // label that says enter password

            panel.add(lblpdub, BorderLayout.CENTER);//  adds label and inputbox 
            panel.add(pass, BorderLayout.CENTER);   // to panel and sets location
            panel.add(btnEnter, BorderLayout.CENTER); //adds button to panel
            pack();                                         // packs controls and

            setLocationRelativeTo(null);    // Implicit "this" if inside JFrame constructor.

            setVisible(true);                               // makes them visible (duh)

        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
            {

                Object source = a.getSource();
            //char array that holds password
            char[] passy = pass.getPassword();
            //characters array to string
            String p = new String(passy);

            //determines if user entered correct password
            if(p.equals(ThePDub))
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome beta user: USERNAME.");
            }
            else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have enter an incorrect password. Please try again.");
            }

    class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

            private Image img;

        public ImagePanel(String img) {
            this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
  }

            public ImagePanel(Image img) {
            this.img = img;
            Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
            setPreferredSize(size);
            setMinimumSize(size);
            setMaximumSize(size);
            setSize(size);
            setLayout(null);
  }

          public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
  }

}
        }
```

Comment: sry. it dosnt display the panels correctly. cant see the background image.

Answer (score 1):

The image displays fine for me. Did you add any debug code to displayed the preferred size of the image to make sure it was read in correctly.

Also, once you get your image working you won't see the components you actually add to the image panel. Do you know what the following line of code does or did you just copy it from somewhere? Get rid of it:

```
setLayout(null);
```

Why do you create an empty panel and then create an ImagePanel?

```
panel = new JPanel(); //creates a panel    
ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("/mousepics/backgroundspacepic.jpeg").getImage());
```

Comment: I tried making the revisions u suggested but it displays the controls and panel correctly now but it wont show picture, just the default background.. any suggestions?

Comment: So where is your debug code verifying that the image was read correctly? You probably don't need the leading "/".